# Agregar Notas a Alumnos de forma masiva laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola Buenas estoy creando un sistema de administración educacional, resulta que tengo creado el modulo para ingresar notas a los alumnos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema es que la manera de ingresar las notas es de a uno por uno
y ahora necesito ingresar las notas de forma masiva (a todos los alumnos de una asignatura). Alguien podría ayudarme por favor, estoy empezando recién con laravel y conozco lo básico. alguna guia o tutorial lo que sea de ayuda. Gracias de antemano.

Estoy acostumbrado a insertar datos como se ve en la imagen de a uno por uno, el clasico crud y su tabla en la cual en cada fila tienes datos y al final Operaciones de Edit o Delete que son facil de realizar porque en ese campo recibes el $id.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que neceesito ahora es insertar varios datos al mismo tiempo a muchos usuarios que en este caso son alumnos, algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

controlador para agregar calificacion de a uno

```
public function agregarCalificacion($id, $idasi)
{   
    $alumno = Alumno::find($id);
    $asignatura = Asignatura::find($idasi);
    return view('agregar/calificacion')->with('alumno',$alumno)->with('asignatura',$asignatura);
}
```

Comment: Edgardo, lo ideal sería que agregaras algo de código, algún intento de lograr esto, por pequeño que sea.

Comment: Editado gracias

Answer (score 2):

Parece ser relativamente simple la solución a tu problema, puedes utilizar arrays generados en el formulario, cuyos índices serían similares a lo que muestras en la tabla ejemplo, algo como esto:

```
@foreach ($alumnos as $alumno)

    <tr>
      <td>{{ $alumno->nombre }}</td>

      @foreach ($notas as $nota)

        <td>{{ Form::text('notas[' . $alumno->id . '][' . $nota->id . ']') }}</td>

      @endforeach

    </tr>

@endforeach
```

Al momento de recibir el formulario tienes un arreglo multidimensional en `$request->notas`, ahí puedes referenciar cada alumno y obtener los valores correspondientes.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes insertar múltiples elementos en la tabla usando un código como el que sigue:

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    ['email' => 'taylor@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
    ['email' => 'dayle@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
]);
```

En la documentación [Laravel, Inserting multiple elements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#inserts)